Dynamic class generation with autocompletion support
I needed something like the TypeScript Utilities but for Pydantic, and I decided to do it myself since the one they offer must be used as a dictionary and I don't like it at all, also it only works for model instances, and not the models themselves.
In case you're interested, you can check it out here but it's pretty small and I'll be showing most of the code in this post.
This is literally all the package has, besides some Dunder methods:
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model


class ExtendedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    """
    A subclass of BaseModel that adds advanced operations for field union, exclusion,
    and difference. This class supports bitwise operators (|, &, -) between instances,
    where the left instance (self) takes precedence for both values and data types.
    """
    
    @classmethod
    def union(cls, _name: str, other: 'ExtendedBaseModel') -> type[BaseModel]:
        """
        Creates a new model that merges fields from the current class and another
        ExtendedBaseModel class. In case of overlapping fields, values and data types
        from the current model (self) take precedence.
        
        Args:
            _name (str): The name for the new model.
            other (ExtendedBaseModel): Another model to merge fields with.
        
        Returns:
            BaseModel: A new model including fields from both the current class and
            the other model.
        """
        # Merge annotations from both models, with precedence for the current class
        fields_data = {*other.__annotations__.items(), *cls.__annotations__.items()}
        # Construct new fields with types and make them required (indicated by `...`)
        new_fields = {field: (annotation, ...) for field, annotation in fields_data}
        return create_model(_name, **new_fields)
    
    @classmethod
    def omit(cls, _name: str, *excluded_fields: str) -> type[BaseModel]:
        """
        Exclude specified fields from the current model to create a new model with
        only the remaining fields.
        
        Args:
            _name (str): The name for the new model.
            *excluded_fields (str): Fields to exclude from the model.
        
        Returns:
            BaseModel: A new model excluding the specified fields.
        """
        # Filter out fields specified in excluded_fields
        new_fields = {
            field: (cls.__annotations__[field], ...)
            for field in cls.__annotations__
            if field not in excluded_fields
        }
        return create_model(_name, **new_fields)
    
    @classmethod
    def pick(cls, _name: str, *included_fields: str) -> type[BaseModel]:
        """
        Generate a new model with only the specified fields from the current model.
        
        Args:
            _name (str): The name for the new model.
            *included_fields (str): Fields to include in the new model.
        
        Returns:
            BaseModel: A new model containing only the specified fields.
        """
        # Select fields specified in included_fields
        new_fields = {
            field: (cls.__annotations__[field], ...)
            for field in cls.__annotations__
            if field in included_fields
        }
        return create_model(_name, **new_fields)
    ...

As documented, it's a Pydantic's BaseModel subclass with some extra methods and bitwise operations that allow you to obtain subversions of a model or model's instance.
The only problem with this it's that the subversion does not provide autocompletion, and I'd like it to do it mostly for type hints.
After some research I found this post where I found a comment from the user igrinis, mentioning dynamically generated .pyi files.
So, this is the solution I came up with:
class ExtendedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def generate_pyi(cls, _name: str, fields: dict):
        """
        Generate a .pyi file for the dynamically created model to provide type hints to IDEs.
        
        Args:
                _name (str): The name of the new model.
                fields (dict): A dictionary of field names and types to be included in the .pyi file.
        """
        makedirs('types/', exist_ok=True)
        pyi_filename = f"types/{_name}.pyi"
        with open(pyi_filename, "w") as pyi_file:
            pyi_file.write(f"from pydantic import BaseModel\n\n")
            pyi_file.write(f"class {_name}(BaseModel):\n")
            
            for field, (field_type, _) in fields.items():
                pyi_file.write(f"    {field}: {field_type.__name__}\n")
    ...

This method works, but IDEs won't recognize them. Is this a problem with my settings, or do I misunderstand the .pyi files theory?
